# Observing Collections in typescript

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, system.reactive

I am using RxJS in typescript and would like to have a generic way to handle changes in collections. A very naive implementation would be something like

```
Observable<Element[]>
```

where every single change in the collection turns into a "broadcast" of all the items included.. This is very cumbersome (and possibly not efficient) to deal with, but my main worry is that it requires checking on the Observer side what has changed.

Let´s imagine that Element is defined like:

```
class Element {
  id: string,
  propA: string,
  propB: string,
  hash(): number {..} // generates a hash based on the properties
}
```

in this case I would like to be notified if and when any of the Elements is added, removed or modified (an Element is considered modified if the `id` remains the same, but some of the properties do not).

In that case I would need some kind of extra Observable pipeline operations that receive the collection and based on the stored (previous) values generates a `CollectionChangedEvent`, which has a type (i.e. `Added`, `Removed`, `Modified`) and an `id` (of the target Element). The modifications being calculated based on the hash of each element.

```
class CollectionChangedEvent {
  type: ChangeType,
  id: string
}
```

Is there something similar already implemented or a better way to go about this?

Comment: I've never used RxJS but, for instance, redux solves this by comparing whether or not the array is the same. By the way, you shouldn't use a hash to check if something changed, as the hash will eventually collide.

Comment: you are right, probably something like elementA.equals(elementB) would be more appropriate here... just interested in a generic way to solve the hndling of observable collections..

Comment: Not really. If you want to have some properties that may trigger events, just use setters instead of plain properties.

Comment: I think maybe I didnt clearly stated this, but what I am interested is in a Rx based solution to handle changes in collections (I do not really use node). The Elements themselves should not emit events, instead the container of those Elements should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at `.scan()`? I think it's appropiate for this. Assuming the source is `source:Observable<Element[]>`, I would do something like:

```
const result:Observable<CollectionChangedEvent[]> = source
    .scan((previous, newElements:Element[]) => {
        const previousElements:Element[] = previous.elements;
        const newChanges = [];
        /* [...] Do huge comparison here, pushing each change you find between newElements and previousElements into newChanges */
        return {
            elements: newElements,
            changes: newChanges
        }
    }, { // Initial values: They are empty arrays
        elements: [],
        changes: []
    })
    .map(acc => acc.changes)
```

Something like that. If you need the `result` observable to be of single `CollectionChangedEvent` instead of an array, you can then `mergeMap` it to `arr => Observable.from(arr)`

Or you can consider doing the oposite, if you have a source stream that gives you `CollectionChangedEvent`, then you can build your result obserable of `Element` or `Element[]` by using `scan()`. This should be easier, because you can treat each event as an imperative command, rather than having to compare arrays for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is enough for you:

```
class Observable extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(protected callback: Function) {
    super();
    this.on("change", callback);
  }
}

class Element extends Observable {

 constructor(public id: string, callback: Function) {
    super(callback);
  }

  private _propA: string;

  set propA(v: string) {
    this.emit("change", {changed: "_propA", newV: v, oldV: this._propA});
    this._propA = v;
  }
}
```

This is a partial example of observable properties using the Node's EventEmitter.